# Django-filer renders incorrectly in admin site

Tags: css, django, django-admin, django-filer

After following the installation instructions on django-filer docs website, I started the development server on my local machine and tested out if everything works. However when I open django admin site and click on filer folders, I can see that the form is not rendering correctly. The whole #content div is aligned to the right site, and the .breadcrumbs-container-inner is a mess. I am using Django 1.9.8 and Django-filer 1.2.4. I attach screen shots of what I get.(Full-window size, and small size window).

Is that a bug of django-filer? Can anyone reproduce the problem, or have had similar problems in the past? How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot #1]
[image: Screenshot #2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way around to solve this issue. All you need to do is install `djangocms-admin-style` into your project.

Problem was reported and hopefully will be solved soon.

There is an open issue ticket on [`GitHub`](https://github.com/divio/django-filer/issues/905).

The answer was found thanks to @ohrstrom and @benzkji suggestions.